# PHP - convert a string with - or + signs to HTML

Tags: php, html, string

How do I convert a string that has a `-` or `+` sign to a html friendly string?
I mean to convert those characters to html notations, like space is `&nbsp;` and so on...

ps: htmlentities doesn't work. I still see the -/+

Comment: Why do you want `-` and `+` to be encoded?

Comment: actually I wanted to get the long `-` character and I thought you need to convert the string to html to get it. but now I see it's a different character :)

Comment: I ended up using only `str_replace('-', '&#8722;', $string)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$string = str_replace('+', '&#43;', $string); // Convert + sign
$string = str_replace('-', '&#45;', $string); // Convert - sign
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is entities for these symbols see: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp

I tested with

```
$str = "- and +"; echo htmlentities($str);
```

and didn't get entities.  According to: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

I would expect them to be encoded if there was encoding available.

Comment: but here there are: http://webdesign.about.com/od/localization/l/blhtmlcodes-math.htm

Comment: While you are correct, it would be best not to use w3schools as a source, see http://w3fools.com/

Comment: You can convert with the str_replace function $string = str_replace('+', '&#43;', $string); 
$string = str_replaced('-', '&#45;', $string);

Comment: Thanks devians!  I hesitated linking them as a source, but just did a quick google search.  Very interesting site.

Answer (score 1):

No idea what you want to accomplish. But this escapes selected characters to html entities:

```
$html = preg_replace("/([+-])/e", '"&#".ord("$1").";"', $html);
```

Comment: He just wants to know how to convert.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, - and + are fine in HTML, and dont have an entity equivalent. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Are you sure you're not thinking of URL encoding?

Comment: He's not asking if it's friendly.  He just wants to know how to convert.

Answer (score 1):

Specify that you want it to use unicode as follows:

```
htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_IGNORE, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the 2nd comment on this page:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php#100388

This will enable more encoding characters.

If you just want to encode some, then this is a little lighter weight:

```
<?php 
$ent = array( 
    '+'=>'&#43;',
    '-'=>'&#43;'
); 

echo strtr('+ and -', $ent); 
?>
```